# Designing lookup table(LUT) for half adder

Tags: fpga

I want to implement half adder using FPGA. For this I need to design CLB, more specifically LUT for half adder. I know LUT gives only one output. But, for half adder we get two output. One for sum and other for carry.

How can I design CLB for half adder?

How can I get two output from LUT? What I am doing wrong?

[image]

From study what I understood about FPGA is, This image represent building block of FPGA which is CLB. CLB consists of LUT, D-Flipflop and MUX.

LUT is used to configure any type of logic gates. AND, OR, NOT or any other complex logic gate. By using program we store output of truth table for say AND gate in LUT. And while we give input to FPGA it goes through LUT via address bar and access specific memory address in LUT. And then output of LUT goes through two paths. Here, we need to choose whether we want our output through combinational circuit or sequential circuit. We use MUX for this selecting purpose. 0 for combinational circuit and 1 for sequential circuit.

Am I correct What I understood so far?

When we need to choose sequential circuit and combinational circuit?

Answer (score 0):

CLBs generally only provide a single output signal.  To have multiple output signals for the same function, the same inputs must be routed in parallel to multiple CLBs, one per output signal.  In the case of a half adder, one CLB generates SUM, the other generates CARRY.  It may be more beneficial to make a 2-bit full adder to better utilize the five or six inputs available at the LUT.  In that case we have five inputs: A[1:0],B[1:0],Cin and install the function over three CLBs to get SUM[1:0],Cout.

To answer the second question the CLB MUX is selected into sequential mode to realize sequential logic (ie: a state machine) and the LUT generates the combinational next state function for the (sequential) CLB.